# Use SQL Function and IN in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to do something like

```
SELECT *
FROM workers w
WHERE lower(w.name) IN ('david', 'will', 'tom')
```

I'm using ActiveRecord and postgresDB with ruby (v2+) and rails(v4+)
I was trying:

```
Worker.select("lower(trim(name)) as n").where({ n: ['david', 'will', 'tom'] }).all
```

and also

```
Worker.where("lower(trim(name))=:name", { name: ['david', 'will', 'tom'] }).all
```

but nothing seems to work.
Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way

```
Worker.where("lower(trim(name)) IN (?)", ['david', 'will', 'tom'])
```